# ApplicationDbContext not showing in scaffold

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a website that has a admin-module, which allows for the admin to do CRUD on all other users. My idea was to add Roles to the default ApplicationUser-class that comes with the **Individual user accounts**-template and then make a scaffolding of the ApplicationUser-class.

However, when im trying do a scaffold of the controller with views using Entity Framework the ApplicationDbContext doesn't show, in spite of it existing in my code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public virtual DbSet<JobExperience> JobExperiences { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        internal static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

The scaffold-attempt can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Try to rebuild the solution

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but no luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily call it a solution, but it was a workaround. Instead of having the ApplicationDbContext located inside my IdentityModel-class I moved it out into its own class. After that I had to do some small tweaks here and there (renaming certain things) and after that it worked

Answer (score -1):

A workaround may be to use the plus icon and generate a new db context.
Then transfer the contents of applicationdbcontext.cs file to the newly generated context.
It should appear after that.